# What is the difference between the parameter c[a][b] and c[][2]

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, parameters, declaration, variable-length-array

Given the following two declarations, what is the difference?

```
int foo ( int a, int b, int c[a][b] ) {
int foo ( int a, int b, int c[][2] ) {
```

I understand the top statement is a "Variable Length Array" (VLA), but I'm not sure I understand what that means. Both of these produce the same result.

```
int foo ( int a, int b, int c[a][b] ) {
  for ( int *p = c[0]; p <= &(c[a-1][b-1]); p++  ) {
    *p = 0; 
  } 
}
```

vs..

```
int foo ( int a, int b, int c[][2] ) {
  for ( int *p = c[0]; p <= &(c[a-1][b-1]); p++  ) {
    *p = 0; 
  } 
}
```

This is my `main`,

```
int main () {
  int m[2][2] = { {1,2},{3,4} };
  foo(2,2,m); 
  printf( "%s %d %d %d %d", "foo", m[0][0],m[0][1],m[1][0],m[1][1] );
  return 0;
}
```

I can not find any resource that sufficiently explains what's going on here.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: A parameter declared as `int c[a][b]` does not “fully” declare a variable-length array. The second dimension is indeed a variable-length array, but the declaration is equivalent to `int (*c)[b]` (except that `a` might be evaluated when the function is called; the C standard is silent about that, and I have seen an implementation that evaluates it and an implementation that does not).

Comment: As edited, both functions will be equivalent (one VLA and one normal array). `c[a][b]` as a parameter is converted to `(*c)[b]` which in VLA terms is a *pointer to array [b]*. The second `c[][2]` will be converted to `(*c)[2]` which is a simple *pointer to array [2]* (no VLA involved). In both cases you set the address `p` to the beginning of each array and will iterate over each of the elements (up to but not including the **last**) setting each to zero.

Answer (score 4):

In `int foo ( int a, int b, int c[a][b] )`, the parameter `c` is declared to be a pointer to an array of `b` `int`. That is, it points to an array of `int` in which the number of elements is `b`.

In `int foo ( int a, int b, int c[][2] )`, the parameter `c` is declared to be a pointer to an array of 2 `int`.

When `b` is two, these declarations are identical for practical purposes.  Technical differences include:

- In the latter declaration, the compiler knows the array has two elements, and it can generate code with 2 built into it. In the former declaration, the compiler does not know from the declaration alone how big the array is. Therefore, when it needs the size of the array for some reason, it must generate code that computes array element locations using `b` at run-time, unless it is able to deduce the value of `b` at compile time by looking at other code in the program.
- In the latter declaration, the C standard is unclear about whether `a` is evaluated or not. That does not matter in this case where `a` is a simple object, but you are also allowed to put expressions there, and expressions can cause observable effects such as printing output. I have seen a C implementation that did evaluate that dimension and a C implementation that did not. I have never seen a real-world program where this mattered.

When a parameter declaration appears in array form, the first dimension is automatically adjusted to be a pointer. This is because C passes arrays only by pointing to the first element, not by passing the value of the entire array as it does with non-array parameters. So a parameter declared as `int foo[a][b][c][d]` is adjusted to `int (*foo)[b][c][d]`. Only the first dimension is adjusted because the pointer does point to actual arrays in memory, so the other dimensions are there; they are not pointers. Allowing parameters to be declared this way is merely a notational convenience.

In both cases, `c` is a pointer to an array of `int`. Commonly, such a parameter points to a first array of `int`, and that array is followed by another, and another, and so on, to form an array of arrays of `int`. This is went the second dimension, `b` or 2, matters. The compiler needs that dimension to know how big the arrays of `int` are, so that, when the source code accesses arrays beyond the first one, the compiler is able to calculate their addresses by multiplying the size of each array of `int` by the array index. In the case of `2`, the array size is constant, and the compiler should generate multiplication by a constant. In the case of `b`, the compiler may have to generate code that fetches `b` from a register or somewhere and multiplies by that.

If `foo` is written to **always** take an array of arrays of 2 `int`, then you should declare the parameter with `2`. If `foo` is written to take arrays of whatever size the caller requests, then you should declare the parameter with `b`.